# Implementation of QuickSort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

A sample implementation of Quick Sort from the internet is:

```
public void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
            return;

        if (low >= high)
            return;

        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int pivot = arr[middle];


        int i = low, j = high;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }

            while (arr[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }


        if (low < j)
            quickSort(arr, low, j);

        if (high > i)
            quickSort(arr, i, high);
    }
}
```

1. Why is the outmost while loop `i<= j` and not `i <j`?
2. Before the recursive calls why the checks `low < j` and `high > i` since low is the leftmost element and high the rightmost element?
3. Why does the swap happen  `if (i <= j)`? Shouldn't it be `i<j`? Sure if they are equal it is swapped with it self?

Comment: Where did this "sample implementation" actually come from (more specifically than "the internet") ? Wouldn't you be better served putting your questions to whoever wrote it?

Comment: @khelwood We are way smarter.

Comment: All of these questions can be answered by trying the changes yourself and using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

1. because you want to sort from 0 to n
2. because you must to part table to check and sort other items

Read more about this sort type, all sort types - then this will be clear and easy :)

Answer (score 0):

1. So it avoids including the i == j element in sorting both the left and right part.
2. So it avoids sorting empty array (low == j)
3. Swap itself yes, but still it needs to move ++i and --j because of the same as already answered in (1).

Answer (score 0):

1. This is beacause of the fact that we do not want to include the point where `i == j` in subsequent sort-calls. This way, we do not sort the point twice.
2. I have no idea. The culling is done in the next step as well.
3. Yes, this is because it takes more lines of code to write that.

Answer (score 0):

1. The usage of i <= j goes with the recursive calls, quickSort(arr, low, j); and quickSort(arr, i, high);.
2. The if's before the recursive calls are redundant, but avoid making recursive calls that just return. The first if statement is meant to handle the initial call.
3. The swap takes less cpu time than using another if statement.

Hoare partition scheme is similar, but it uses pre-decrement and pre-increment, and breaks when i >= j (like a while i < j ). C++ example:

```
void QuickSort(int a[], int lo, int hi)
{
    if (lo >= hi)
        return;
    int p = a[(lo + hi) / 2];
    int i = lo, j = hi;
    i--;                        // partition
    j++;
    while (1)
    {
        while (a[++i] < p) ;
        while (a[--j] > p) ;
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
    }
    QuickSort(a, lo, j);
    QuickSort(a, j + 1, hi);
}
```